# Convert Dictionary<object, string> to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of `<object, string>` that I know for a fact can be converted to `<string, string>`.  Rather than loop over the 1st dictionary to build up the second one, are there `Convert` methods or something else that can do this in a single call?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? what code are you trying yo write?

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev I'm trying to convert my Dictionary<object, string> to Dictionary<string, string> in as few lines of code as feasible.

Comment: @larryq - You could write an extension method that does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by direct, if you are looking for something like `List<T>.ConvertAll` method, no there is no method like this for Dictionary. Even if there is you have to create a new dictionary anyway, so:

```
var newDic = myDictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.Value);
```

Comment: I would avoid using `.ToString()` as it is not a "convert" or "cast" function. It could return something else.